# Visual Studio 2014 CTP - places computer in unsupported state

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I'm about to download Visual Studio 2014 CTP from http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-14-ctp-vs but that page says

> Installing a CTP release will place a computer in an unsupported
>   state.

What *exactly* does that mean, or what do they mean by that? Has anybody tried VS 2014 CTP yet, and what's it like? Is it stable enough to make simple desktop apps or whatever? Should I not install it?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes "not supported" means "doesn't work", but in this case "unsupported" means you can't open a support ticket with Microsoft for any issues you encounter on that machine or with that software.

Answer (score 3):

> What exactly does that mean, or what do they mean by that?

It basically means that, if you install it, your OS is no longer supported by Microsoft, and will need to be reinstalled later.

In practice, it means you should only install Visual Studio 2014 CTP into a virtual machine, and definitely avoid installing on a production/main system.

Answer (score 3):

"CTP" software from Microsoft is "community technology preview" software. It's not necessarily release-quality, and hasn't necessarily gone through the usual rounds of bug fixing and polish that should be expected of release software.

Thus, it might be (and almost certainly is) buggy. Thus, installing it should be done at your own risk, because it's not officially supported yet.

It's probably safe to install, though I would not necessarily recommend switching to it for production work (usually I install these things on VMs to avoid potential corruption of my actual work machines).